# UGC Image Upload Form

Tags: landing-page, marketing-cloud

Is it possible to create a SFMC Landing Page which contains a form to allow a customer to upload an image, and some associated meta data about the image? Obviously you would want to restrict the file types/sizes that can be uploaded etc

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to create an SFMC landing page (HTML microsite)  which will allow your subscribers to upload an image. you can see that in the properties section there is meta description and meta keywords that you can use. about file size limit coding you have to use javascript to set the limit.

Hope this helps

Comment: Where do the images get uploaded to? Don't suppose you can point me to a tutorial or guide for this can you?

Comment: Care to substantiate this with some details?